# Removing leading and trailing spaces from string

Tags: python, string

It is hard for me to understand that what's going on in the following code. I am actually trying to remove the leading and trailing space from the string in python. The string has two leading and trailing spaces like this

```
"  Hello World!  "
```

I tried following simple code to remove the spaces

```
s = "  Hello World!  "
temp = s.split(" ")
//output of temp -> ['', '', 'hello', 'world!', '', '']
for x in temp:
   if x == "":
     temp.remove(x)
print(temp)
//output of temp  -> ['hello', 'world!', '', '']
```

So it only removes the leading trailing spaces and not trailing. Can anyone explain why this function skipping the last two spaces? 
Note: I don't want to use `strip` function, just curious about what's going on under the hood

Comment: I'd recommend against using `remove` in a loop on the same list, as you'll end up skipping items. But you can do a simple  `temp = [x for x in temp if x != ""]`

Comment: If you are curious about what exactly happens, run your code through a  step-by-step debugger and look at the values of x and temp at each iteration. that should be interesting

Comment: `temp = [x for x in temp if x ]` will also work since an empty string is falsy.